# Typescript. Typing key value pairs in form structure

Tags: typescript, typing

I am typing a form structure which is working pretty well. However there is something interesting happening in the validation part of a formfield in the fields.

My Visual Code will tell me that the validation 'required2' in the `phone` constant is not correct, since it has to be 'required'.
However, when you look at the phonefield item in the fields collection of the `form` constant, it is not complaining the `required2` is not allowed.
Only when I make required required in the interface, will the form constant be invalid.

My goal is to restrict the validation per form field so that someone can't add a key/value to the validation dictionary that is not typed.

Interesting to know that when I change phonenumber to phonenumber2 the typing will be incorrect. But changing the required key doesn't matter since it is not required.

My interfaces

```
declare type fields           = IPhoneField | ISelectField ..etc;

export interface IPage {
  title?:               string;
  buttons?:             IButton[];
  fields:               fields[];
  showOn?:              IDictionary <string | number>;
}

export interface IForm {
  modelPreset:          IDictionary <string | number>;
  successPageConfig?:   IDictionary <string | number | boolean>;
  presentation:         pagePresentation;
  pages:                IPage[];
}

interface IField {

  label:                string;
  model:                string;
  placeholder?:         string;
  addon?:               string;
  showOn?:              IDictionary <string | number>;
  maxlength?:           number;

}

export interface IPhoneField extends IField {
  type:                 'phone';
  validation:    {
    required?:          string;
    phonenumber:        string;
  };
}
```

My code

```
const phone: IPhoneField = {
  "label":"Phone Number",
  "model":"phonenumber",
  "type":"phone",
  "placeholder":"Phone number",
  "validation":{
      "required2":"A phone number is required",
      "phonenumber":"Please enter a valid phone number",

    }
};

const form: IDictionary<IForm> = {
  "form1":{
      "pages":[
        {
            "fields": [
              {
                  "label":"Phone Number",
                  "model":"phonenumber",
                  "type":"phone",
                  "placeholder":"Phone number",
                  "validation":{
                    "required2":"A phone number is required",
                    "phonenumber":"Please enter a valid phone number"
                  }
              }
            ]
        }
      ]
  }
};
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? Is it a bug of Typescript?

See playground link:  [NEW playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=declare%20type%20fields%20%3D%20IPhoneField%20%7C%20IEmailField%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20IDictionary%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5Bindex%3A%20string%5D%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20IPage%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20fields%3A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fields%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20IForm%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20pages%3A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20IPage%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20IEmailField%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20type%3A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'email'%3B%0D%0A%20%20validation%3A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20required%3F%3A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20email%3A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20IPhoneField%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20type%3A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'phone'%3B%0D%0A%20%20validation%3A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20required%3F%3A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20phonenumber%3A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aconst%20phone%3A%20IPhoneField%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%22type%22%3A%22phone%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%22validation%22%3A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22required2%22%3A%22A%20phone%20number%20is%20required%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22phonenumber%22%3A%22Please%20enter%20a%20valid%20phone%20number%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20form%3A%20IDictionary%3CIForm%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%22form1%22%3A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22pages%22%3A%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22fields%22%3A%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22type%22%3A%22phone%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22validation%22%3A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22required2%22%3A%22A%20phone%20number%20is%20required%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22phonenumber%22%3A%22Please%20enter%20a%20valid%20phone%20number%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B)

Comment: Can you add a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) link which includes all of the definitions and the code that is problematic?

Comment: See play ground link in my original question

Comment: The playground link has the same error in the `form` structure.

Comment: @NitzanTomer yes, the playground works perfect. My VS Code or Gulp build will not stumble over the `form` constant. Should I report this on the TS Github page or should I investigate further?

Comment: If it works well in playground then there's no problem with the compiler and there's nothing to report. What version of typescript are you using? How does it react when you use `tsc` directly?

Comment: Okay, I have updated the playground and found what is causing the issue: I declare a pipe of fields at the top and because of the Pipe, the type checking breaks with the array of fields. It also stops complaining now in the Playground. So it is not a typescript issue but a misconception or typing issue I introduced myself. I will try to look for another way to create an array of fields in the typing.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug in TypeScript. You're creating objects of types different than their signatures so type inference doesn't work.

First: The `required2` in `phone` is not allowed on `validation` because it's an extraneous field. It doesn't have anything to do with the existing `required?` field. Since you're using type inference, adding a field causes the inferred type to be different even though the object still satisfies the interface.

If you really want to to do it, you could mark it as of that type. Since you don't have an interface or type name, you'd have to do this:

```
const phone: IPhoneField = {
  "label":"Phone Number",
  "model":"phonenumber",
  "type":"phone",
  "placeholder":"Phone number",
  "validation":{
    "required2":"A phone number is required",
    "phonenumber":"Please enter a valid phone number",
  } as { required?: string, phonenumber: string},
};
```

But of course it's better to do it like this:

```
interface IPhoneValidation {
  required?:          string;
  phonenumber:        string;
}

export interface IPhoneField extends IField {
  type:                 'phone';
  validation:           IPhoneValidation;
}

const phone: IPhoneField = {
  "label":"Phone Number",
  "model":"phonenumber",
  "type":"phone",
  "placeholder":"Phone number",
  "validation":{
    "required2":"A phone number is required",
    "phonenumber":"Please enter a valid phone number",
  } as IPhoneValidation,
}
```

Now, as to why it's not complaining about the error in the form. It's because your form's validation fields are not getting type checked at all.

Since you haven't posted the `IDictionary` implementation, it's a bit of a guess to pinpoint why that is. But with a boilerlate dictionary implementation:

```
interface IDictionary<T> {
  [K: string]: T;
}
```

I get errors in the `form` declaration so it cannot be assigned. It's important to notice that the error will not come from `required2`, simply because you're composing a deep set of objects of no type and only assigning them to `form` at the very end, and that's when an invalid assignment is noticed. You can read the error message and you'll see it. I get:

```
Type '{ "form1": { "pages": { "fields": { "label": string; "model": string; "type": "phone"; "placehold...' is not assignable to type 'IDictionary<IForm>'.
  Property '"form1"' is incompatible with index signature.
    Type '{ "pages": { "fields": { "label": string; "model": string; "type": "phone"; "placeholder": string...' is not assignable to type 'IForm'.
      Property 'modelPreset' is missing in type '{ "pages": { "fields": { "label": string; "model": string; "type": "phone"; "placeholder": string...'.
```

Which is a mouthful (and clamped) but somewhat indicates that there's an errors deep down.

If you type your objects during assignment, you'd get the error earlier so it's easier to parse, or not get them at all if the objects satisfy the interface. For example:

```
const form: IDictionary<IForm> = {
    "form1": {
        "pages": [
            {
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "label": "Phone Number",
                        "model": "phonenumber",
                        "type": "phone",
                        "placeholder": "Phone number",
                        "validation": {
                            "required2": "A phone number is required",
                            "phonenumber": "Please enter a valid phone number"
                        } as IValidation,
                    } as IField,
                ]
            } as IPage,
        ]
    }
};
```

In the above case everything will work fine, or otherwise you'll see errors when they exist.

The reason why TypeScript does all these checks and doesn't automatically type cast something as an interface with extraneous fields is to be more strict about avoiding typing mistakes. If it did allow anything, you could type a `requird` and never realize it wasn't `required` since it's an optional field. In other words, `{required2: ..., phonenumber: ...}` is *allowed* as a `validation` object, but not *automatically recognized* without the type annotation.

If you want interfaces to allow other properties automatically, you can do:

```
interface IValidation {
  required?:          string;
  phonenumber:        string;
  [propName:string]:  any;
}
```

Read about "excess property checks" [in the interface manual](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) for more information on that.

Comment: Hi thanks for your long answer. If you check the main story I have added a playground link. You were right about the dictionary interface. Strangely, in the playground I do get the appropriate behaviour. `Required2` is not allowed in the phonefield structure within fields of pages. My Webpack TS-loader and TS-lint and my VS Code do not complain about required2. So I am seeing a discrepancy there. My versions are: ```"ts-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "tslint": "^4.3.1",
    "tslint-loader": "^3.3.0",
    "typescript": "^2.2.1",```.
Maybe I should upgrade tslint?

Comment: TSlint should not matter. You may have an incorrect version of TypeScript, although 2.2.x should be fine. Maybe make sure your VSC's `settings.json` file is set to `"typescript.tsdk": "node_modules/typescript/lib"` so it can use your local project TSC, not the editor's one. And that you don't have TypeScript installed globally.

Comment: Hi, I just did what you suggested: pointing to local TS version in node_ modules and it doesn't change the issue. The `form` const is still not marked as having an error while the validation is set incorrectly. The playground link I have added to the main story behaves as aspected. My visual code and gulp build process is not. Should I report this on the TS Github page?

Comment: check my comment under the main story comments. Playground has been updated, I didn't include a pipe of field types that really made a difference :(

Comment: Ah, I see it now. Yeah, it seems the pipe is the culprit. TSC was actually smarter before: even without any type casting, it could tell you where the issue was. But with more types, it gets lost. It appears to me it SHOULD have known since your interfaces are identifiable by `type`. But it still makes it confused. I wouldn't call it a "bug", but it certainly should have been able to identify the specific error. (I mean, it does, it just doesn't know where to put the highlight).

Comment: agreed. So what should I do with this? Unfortunately it doesn't break during build time this way. I would like to lock down the validation configuration per field. It's all coming from JSON and then gets parsed into a typed CONST and injected into Angular. I cant really pull all fields apart and put separate typing on it.

Comment: I'm not sure in this case. If it's coming from JSON, and it has to be dynamic, there's not much you could do with any language to make sure it follows a certain pattern. For dynamic JSON data, I'd probably use a real JSON schema validator like [ajv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ajv) to make sure the data is conformant to what one expects. That's what I use on my own TS projects that digest external data; the schema validator is part of the linting process.

Comment: JSON Schema validator looks interesting, thanks. I will have a look at that. I am going to post my playground example on the Github page and see if people deem it a bug (the piping of multiple types killing the nested structures). Thanks for your time